# Command line build an iOS sample project without development team

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I created a Hello Word project in Xcode and built it in the simulator it successfully. But when I tried build the same project by command line, I received this error:

```
Signing for "PROJECT" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
```

Why building by Xcode is not requires a development team and by command line is required?

EDIT:

This is Xcode Signing configuration:
[image]

This is the command that I am trying run:

```
xcodebuild CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic -configuration Debug
```

Comment: Do you have a development team configured in Xcode but not with the command line utilities?

Comment: Hi! No, I do not have a development team configured in Xcode too. Check my edit with the print.

Comment: Try to manually setting the "-sdk" to "iphonesimulator"

Comment: @arturdev Your suggestion worked like a charm. Please add your text as Answer to me to mark your answer as correct. Tks.

Comment: @MuriloAlborghette glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manually set the "-sdk" to "iphonesimulator"